# Long tasks with Kotlin Coroutine

Tags: kotlin-coroutines

I am new to Kotlin coroutines and trying to understand its concept.
I tested below code, all I wanted that last print statement should print before delay but I couldn't achieve that. I tried Dispatcher.IO in runblocking with assumption that it will run asynchronously but still no benefit.

fun main() {

```
println(Thread.currentThread().name)

runBlocking(Dispatchers.IO) {
    println("first "+Thread.currentThread().name)
    kotlinx.coroutines.delay(3000)
    println("second "+Thread.currentThread().name)
}
println("last "+Thread.currentThread().name)
```

}

output:

main

first DefaultDispatcher-worker-1

second DefaultDispatcher-worker-1

last main

Answer (score 0):

runBlocking will finish before going to the next line.. but in that block you can run a launch(Dispatched.IO){} block

```kotlin
println(Thread.currentThread().name)

runBlocking() {
    launch(Dispatchers.IO){
        println("first "+Thread.currentThread().name)
        kotlinx.coroutines.delay(3000)
        println("second "+Thread.currentThread().name)
    }
    println("still in blocking (runs at the same time as coroutines)"+Thread.currentThread().name)
}
println("last (runs after al coroutines are finsihed)"+Thread.currentThread().name)
```

Comment: I tried putting launch(Dispathers.IO) in runblocking but still only after delay last print statement prints.

'''fun main() {

    println(Thread.currentThread().name)

    runBlocking(Dispatchers.IO) {
        println("first "+Thread.currentThread().name)
        launch(Dispatchers.IO) {  kotlinx.coroutines.delay(3000) }
        println("second "+Thread.currentThread().name)
    }

    println("last "+Thread.currentThread().name)
}'''

Comment: @Sharad just changed my answer a bit, does that work?

Comment: No that also doesn't work. last print statement prints only after delay of 3 secs. Which as per my understanding should not because we are using launch(Dispatchers.IO)

Comment: My return is this: 
#main
#still in blocking main
#first DefaultDispatcher-worker-1
#second DefaultDispatcher-worker-1
#last main
"last" is outside of run blocking, so it will run after all coroutines are finished. but "still in blocking" runs alongside the launch code

Comment: you are right but I wanted "last" to run alongside runblocking.
Is that possible at all?



One more question, #first DefaultDispatcher-worker-1 is different thread here?

Comment: Nope, just put what you want in last in runBlocking()... it doesn't switch threads, and only anything that you put in launch() will run in a different thread. Everything placed after runBlocking will run only after all the coroutines and the mainthread in runblocking is finished.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209521/discussion-between-typhaon-and-sharad).

Comment: `Dispatchers.IO` is irrelevant and unnecessary here. It is needed only for running _blocking_ operations within the coroutine code. The `runBlocking` dispatcher will work the same way because all you do is call `delay`. No thread switching is needed to achieve concurrency among coroutines (that's exactly what they are for).